# Random word on webpage every 1/10th of a second

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, web-applications

I'm developing a small web-based (javascript) 'application' for an art project. The thing is called 'Poetry Generator', and it's a script that generates random poems based on user input.

The script has to display a random word to the user every 1/10th of a second. The wordlist used, counts 109.582 words.

I've already tried different solutions:

1. put all the words in a text file, and get a random line of the textfile -> too slow (and the user has to download a 3MB text-file before being able to use the application)
2. put all the words in an array in the Javascript. -> javascript arrays apparently can't handle 109.585 items
3. pull the words from a database using jQuery's Ajax function with a Javascript interval function -> this solution worked perfectly when testing on my localhost, but once uploaded to a real web-environment, this method proved to be too slow. (And I could imagine that my hosting provider wouldn't be so happy if I executed 10 query's to their server every second.)

So.. Does anybody knows a different approach that I could use to show a random word on a webpage every 1/10th of a second? It doesn't necessarily has to use php or javascript, as long as it runs in a browses, I'm happy!

Thanks in advance

Teis

Comment: Split your 3 MB file in smaller files, and download them in a random order. While they download you can still start pulling random words from the chunks you already have.

Comment: Have you tried a combination of 2 and 3, but modify 3 in such a way that you take a random 600 so you need only to do one query to your server every minute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason you have to pull the entire dataset every tenth of a second. Pull a reasonable amount from a database every minute (which would be about 600 words), load it into a local javascript object, and iterate through it.

When either the array index becomes high enough or the timer hits one minute, poll for another set of 600.

When dealing with times as low as a tenth of a second, you don't want to have to invoke the server EVERY single time! You could even load the entire data set into `memcached` and poll for random words, thus skipping costly database calls, as the entire data set is loaded into memory.

Comment: beat me to the punch - this is the way to go

Comment: Well, I should have been able to think about that myself :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Updated with a `memcached` option, which is probably overkill, heh.

Comment: There's a couple of nice things about this. The best one is that you don't need any randomization on the JS side at all - just show the words one by one and leave the rest to the server. This have the added benefit that randomly picking words from a small dataset in JS have a high risk of repeating words, and it's not a good distribution since the client-side randomization only works with the smaller dataset, i.e., you run a high risk of repeating words within that subset, but you have no way of randomly selecting words from outside the subset.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to load only a subset of your words into your JS array.
Maybe you could try to load only 1000 (random) words from your database and show them.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't need to generate insanely long text, you cold divide the randomization into two steps:

**First** preselect some of the words server-side (let's say -- 5000?)

**Then**, client-side, use JS to pick some more at random, from the preselected words.

Pros: No additional requests necessary; JS should handle array that big